# Событие прокрутки listview

Tags: java, android

Имеется уже заполненный listview. Как мне отловить событие, когда его прокрутили в начало списка(то есть наверх)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

     @Override
     public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                          int firstVisibleItem,
                          int visibleItemCount,
                          int totalItemCount) {
        boolean firstItemVisible = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
        boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = mListView.getChildAt(0) != null 
                                        && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
        if (firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible) {
           //этот блок выполняется при прокрутке списка вверх
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
     }

});
```